# In a Vue app how do I check if a component tag is available?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

Let's say I have this collection:

```
products: [
  { name: "ProductOne", value: 20 },
  { name: "ProductTwo", value: 30 },
  { name: "ProductRandom", value: 50 }
]
```

I want to be able to use a specific component based on the product name, or fall back to a default:

```
<div v-for="product in products">
  <product-one-and-two :product="product" v-if="componentExists(product.name)"></product-one-and-two>
  <default-product v-else :product="product"></default-product>
</div>
```

This is an over-simplified example, in real life I have thousands of products and we'd like to just create product or category-specific template files without having to pollute the main app with conditionals. We want the component authors to not have to go through another team to have their new template added to the pipeline.

Is this possible at all with Vue?

Answer (score 2):

I would do it with dynamic compontens `<component :is=""></component>`

```
  <component :product="product" :is="product.name"></component>
```

At `:is` you can dynamically add the component name, and it will be rendered.

If you create a new template for a product you just need to do 2 things.

Add a new object to your array `products`

```
products: [
  { name: "ProductOne", value: 20 },
  { name: "ProductTwo", value: 30 },
  { name: "ProductRandom", value: 50},
  { name: "newProduct", value: 34 }
]
```

and register the new component.

```
import newProduct from "../path/to/newProduct.vue";
components: {
   newProduct
}
```

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated. It's the way we'll probably go if we can't figure out a way around having to register the components with the app (we have a template pipeline that renders everything in a product_templates/ directory)

Comment: @NickM thats everything i can offer as help for now